# Check hover state with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there anyway to check for a hover state? I have a multipurpose link that switches purposes on click (basically active / inactive). I want to add a transition effect but in order for it to look perfect I'd like to do a *possible* mouse out effect if the cursor is still hovering over the link, otherwise I'd like for it to go ahead with the effect. Basically this is what I'm looking to do:

```
$(link).click(function(){
  $(this).animate({whatever}, 500, function(){
    if ($(this).is(':hover')) {
      $(this).one('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).animate({whatever}, 500);
      });
    } else {
      $(this).animate({whatever}, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

The ':hover' state doesn't exist.. so is there something that I can do?

Comment: If you click a link, you would already have triggered the hover state. I can't get my brain around what you're trying to achieve..

Answer (score 0):

There's a `mouseenter` event. However, from my experience it is not exactly like `hover`.